# Stratified Cox model

Tags: survival, cox-model, stratification

I am working on fitting a Cox model to predict. But several predictors violated the proportional hazards assumption. I am gonna to do stratified Cox model to adjust them. But the results of stratified Cox model would not include any information or influence of those stratified predictors. As I really want to see the influence of one important predictor, I assume it's very important for the outcome of my data. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could include an interaction with time in your model. You definitely want to read Singer/Willett (2003) *Applied longitudinal data analysis: modeling change and event occurrence*, chapter 15, in particular section 15.3 *Nonproportional Hazard Models via Interactions with Time*. Google books has a [preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=dJHuohXPDoMC&lpg=PT523&vq=stratified&hl=de&pg=PT524#v=onepage&q&f=false).